# How to check if the input is a specific type?

Tags: haskell

```
data Term = TNull            -- null term
          | TBool Bool       -- boolean data
          | TInt Int         -- integer data
          | TSymbol String   -- symbolic data
          | TPair Term Term  -- pairs
          | TVar LVar        -- logic variable
          deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

walk :: Term -> Substitution -> Term
walk term substitution = undefined

type Substitution = Map.Map LVar Term
```

I want to check if  `term` is a logic variable.

If it is not a logic variable or not in Substitution mapping, then return it. Otherwise, call walk recursively to see if the Substitution mapping another logic variable. How can I implement it?

---

As  AJFarmar mentioned, I tried pattern matching on it.

```
walk TVar substitution = if substitution Tvar
    walk (substitution Tvar) substitution
walk _ substitution = TVar
```

But it seems doesn't work.

Comment: Use pattern matching, and functions provided in `Data.Map`.

Comment: Pattern matching requires parentheses - try using `walk (TVar substitution) = ...`. Also you might find [`Map.lookup`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.19/containers-0.5.11.0/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:lookup) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pattern matching:

```
walk :: Term -> Substitution -> Term
walk term@(TVar lvar) sub = Map.findWithDefault term lvar sub
walk (TPair term1 term2) sub = TPair (walk term1 sub) (walk term2 sub)
walk term _ = term
```

Comment: I think you give a nice solution. But it fails in a test. `walk true Map.empty`. It suppose to return `True`. I can't figure it out. `? Variable not in scope: true :: Term
    ? Perhaps you meant data constructor ‘True’ (imported from Prelude)`

Comment: `true` is not a value of type `Term`. Only the data constructors used in your `data Term` declaration can be used to create values of type `Term`. You would need to use `walk (TBool True) Map.empty`